# How to secure Python development enviroments?

Tags: python, security

I have read about malicious and obfuscated packages on PyPI.

I wonder if I can trust this source, or under what circumstances, and if there are alternatives to securing a development/production environment in Python.

There is, for example, Anaconda distribution which provides curated sources in their `main` channel but of course, it is neither super up to date nor are all packages available.
I assume `conda-forge` channel has the same security loopholes as PyPi.
An outdated package goes hand in hand with security risks as well, so what to do?

Is a tool like [bandit](https://bandit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) adding security as well as e.g. developing in Docker containers?

What measures should every developer take besides common sense?